# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: javascript, html, web, worker

I currently have a web worker trying to accept 1 argument

```
wworker = postMessage([textCoords[0], textCoords[1], latlong[0], latlong[1]]);
wworker.addEventListener('message', findDistance);
```

However, an error keeps popping up on console: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present." AFAIK the postMessage 2nd argument is optional.

and here is my worker.js

```
var distance;

function findDistance(event) {
var destinationLat, destinationLon, originLat, originLon, haversineLat, haversineLon, thetaLat, thetaLon;
destinationLat = event.data[0] * (Math.PI/180);
destinationLon = event.data[1] * (Math.PI/180);
originLat = event.data[2] * (Math.PI/180);
originLon = event.data[3] * (Math.PI/180);
thetaLat = destinationLat - originLat;
thetaLon = destinationLon - originLon;
haversineLat = (1-Math.cos(thetaLat))/2;
haversineLon = (1-Math.cos(thetaLon))/2;
distance = 2 * 6376 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(haversineLat + Math.cos(originLat) * Math.cos(destinationLat) * haversineLon));
postMessage(distance);
}

self.addEventListener('message', findDistance);
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? Why is error message at `Window`?

Comment: like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/RzooBuChcvigYKmXD6SF?p=info

Comment: `wworker = postMessage()` is not correct. Why do you attach a new `message` event handler within `for` loop?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. so in case the textfile I am reading there are multiple lines, I will loop multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `.postMessage()` on `Worker`; also you are attaching a new `message` event at each iteration of `for` loop. Move `wworker.addEventListener('message', findDistance);` outside of `for` loop, call `wworker.postMessage()` within `for` loop

```
var wworker = new Worker("assets/scripts/webworker.js");
wworker.addEventListener('message', findDistance);

for(i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    var temp = lines[i].split(",");     

    wworker.postMessage([textCoords[0], textCoords[1], latlong[0], latlong[1]]);

    textCoords.shift();
    textCoords.shift();
}
```